# Hide/show anchor tags on smaller screen

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following markup

```
<div id="contact-buttons-bar" class="slide-on-scroll" data-top="250px" style="left: 0px;">
<button class="contact-button-link show-hide-contact-bar" style="left: 0px;">
<a class="contact-button-link cb-ancor facebook" target="_blank" title="Follow on Facebook" href="https://www.facebook.com/" style="left: 0px;">
<a class="contact-button-link cb-ancor linkedin" target="_blank" title="Visit on LinkedIn" href="https://www.linkedin.com/" style="left: 0px;">
<a class="contact-button-link cb-ancor twitter" target="_blank" title="Follow on Twitter" href="https://www.twitter.com" style="left: 0px;">
<a class="contact-button-link cb-ancor youtube" target="_blank" title="Follow us on YouTube" href="https://www.youtube.com" style="left: 0px;">
</div>
```

On the click event of `show-hide-contact-bar` button I hide all the `anchor` tags by toggling class `cb.hidden`. That function looks like:

```
$('body').on('click', '.show-hide-contact-bar', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    $('.show-hide-contact-bar').find('.fa').toggleClass('fa-angle-right fa-angle-left');
    oContainer.find('.cb-ancor').toggleClass('cb-hidden');
  });
```

which works spot on.

Now what I'm trying to achieve is that, if the screen size is less than 768 I want to hide all the anchor tags to start of with and only show on click event. I've tried

```
var width = $(window).width()
if (width < 768) {
  $('.show-hide-contact-bar').find('.fa').removeClass('fa-angle-left').addClass('fa-angle-right');
  $('.show-hide-contact-bar').find('.cb-ancor').toggleClass('cb-hidden');
}
```

But it does not seem to work. The social-bar is not hidden to start of with.

Initially, I animate the div as:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $('#contact-buttons-bar').animate({ left : 0 });
}, 200);
```

As mentioned by @edisoni.1337, I should use `toggle()`. I tried using it but the styling of the anchor tags goes really weird:

[image]

Comment: Why not use css media queries?

Comment: @eisbehr I've not considered that as of yet tbh, would it be possible if you can provide an example please

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use media queries for that with css only.

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .cb-ancor {
        display:none;
    }
}
```

Also here you have an updated [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/emwq6yd4/3/) for your button click fix
I have used the `.toggle()` from jquery so it will save a lot of work for you.
Here you have a post from w3schools [page](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp) so you can better understand how this works

Comment: Thanks for this, I just tried your suggestion, but now my `show-hide-contact-bar` click event doesn't show the hidden anchor tags

Comment: It's doesn't show because you are using wrong jquery function then because you are toggling the class. You should use  oContainer.find('.cb-ancor').toggle();

Comment: If I use `toggle()` the anchor tag styling goes really weird. I'll update OP to show what I mean

Comment: Please create a jsfiddle and i will check  and fix it :)

Comment: I've created a fiddle **[here](https://jsfiddle.net/emwq6yd4/1/)** please note it works well for screen size greater than 768 but as soon as I make the screen size small i.e. less than 768 then the issue occurs. In order to see the problem make the screen small and refresh the fiddle, then you'll understand what I mean

Comment: So you need these icons to be displayed as they are displayed when you are in screen bigger that 768px ?

Comment: On the load I want the icons to be hidden and when clicked then shown.. Similar to bigger screen but kind of opposite

Comment: What did you changed? They're hidden on the big screen too, but I want them to be shown on big screen at all time unless click on the toggle button.

Comment: check this now https://jsfiddle.net/emwq6yd4/3/ also you might want to add an windows.rezise event

Comment: That's exactly what I want, I currently get the window width by calling `$(window).width();` Any particular reason you're suggesting `windows.resize` event?

Comment: Cool :) I will update my answer and mark as correct and vote up :) i suggested if you are testing it with manually changing your windows size

Comment: Yes that'll be great! Thank you for the help and support, I appreciate it